# Is there a single adverb meaning 'in common'?

Tags: vocabulary, adverbs

The adverb `commonly` in the sense of 'in common' is now obsolete as shown in [this wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commonly):

> 1. as a rule; frequently; usually
> 2. (obsolete) in common; familiarly

Is there a single adverb ending with '-ly' that can be used instead of 'in common'?

---

Here's an example:

> Intersecting lines have one point **in common**.

Comment: Please show us a sample sentence that would include the word you're seeking.

Comment: There's a long list of synonyms here but if you provide context it may help pin it down: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/jointly?s=t

Comment: @aparente001 I've added an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If two things have X in common, you can say the two things **share** X. You could also use the adverb [jointly](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/jointly).

Comment: I guess this might work with the example sentence OP just provided: Lines *r* and *s* jointly pass through Point *P*.  It's quite unusual -- but I guess it does satisfy OP's request.